# How to create a new instance in Angularjs? CRUD's save method doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, crud

When I'm trying to create a new task, nothing happens and no request being sent. Why is that so? How can I debug the issue?

[Here's how it looks](http://gfycat.com/DesertedThoseKissingbug)

Here's **$scope.add** function

```
 var app = angular.module('Tasks', ['ngResource', 'xeditable']);

  app.factory('Task', [
    '$resource', function($resource) {
      return $resource('/tasks/:id', {
        id: '@id'
      }, {
        update: {
          method: 'PUT'
        }
      });
    }
  ]);

  this.TasksCtrl = [
    '$scope', 'Task', function($scope, Task) {

      $scope.add = function() {
        var task;
        task = Task.create($scope.newTask);
        $scope.tasks.push(task);
        return $scope.newTask = {};
      };
  ];
```

Here's my **html** part.

```
<div ng-controller='TasksCtrl' class='tasks-container'>
  <form ng-submit='add()'>
    <input type='text' ng-model='newTask.title'/>
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-sm'>
      <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span> Add
    </button>
  </form>
```

Comment: you're not adding a `create`-function you're adding a `update`-function to your resource class. Try `task = Task.update($scope.newTask);` instead

Comment: You're right. But how can update have something to do with POST request? I'm confused

Comment: not exactly sure what you mean. You're the one declaring the `update`-function as a PUT request in your factory `Task`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form has an `ng-submit` directive that gets called when the form is submitted. But you don't have a submit button on your form (`<button type='button'>` does not submit the form). Change this:

```
<button type='submit' class='btn btn-default btn-sm'>
```

and it should work.

Comment: It helped partially. Thanks anyway. Now I have another problem